What exactly is going on for the handful of verbs which have an imperative -мте conjugation?
There are some Russian verbs which have an imperative conjugation ending in -мте, such as идёмте. But what exactly is going on here? It feels to me like it's a mix of the first person plural imperative and second person plural imperative conjugations (as in, "guys, let's go").
I've seen this referred to as just the first person plural imperative conjugation (cf. идёмте on Wiktionary), but I don't think that makes sense, because it wouldn't be used when speaking to someone whom you would address as ты.
Does anyone have any ideas?


It feels to me like it's a mix of the first person plural imperative and second person plural imperative conjugations (as in, "guys, let's go").

This is exactly what's happened.
The second person imperatives in the singular and in the plural differ in the ending -те: беги/бегите, ешь/ешьте, спи/спите etc.
Russian doesn't have dedicated forms of the imperative for persons other than the second, so it repurposes the indicative perfective forms: закурим!, поспим!, пойдём!, and also imperfective forms for verbs of motion: идём!, летим!, едем!, etc, for the first person plural imperative.
The paradigm for the second person imperative is very simple and uniform (just add -те), and at the same time very important for distinguishing between politeness levels. Through a process known as analogical change, the same paradigm started to be used for the first-person imperative somewhere around the XVIII century. It felt wrong to distinguish between иди and идите in the second person imperative, but use the same идём towards everybody in the first person plural. So the ending -те was repurposed to distinguish between the "singular/singular we" (me and you alone) vs. "singular/plural we" (me and y'all).
Around the late XIX century, people started to use the past forms of some perfective verbs of motion as another way to convey the first-person plural imperative: пошли!, поехали!, полетели! etc. The same analogical change has happened to these forms as well, and these days it's not uncommon to hear the imperative forms пошлите, поехалите, etc., even though many speakers find these forms objectionable.

In my experience, the usage of these -мте forms is very limited. Anything beyond идёмте, пойдёмте and пройдёмте sounds 18th century to me: сядемте, закуримте... even поедемте.

@SergeySlepov: this post is an extract from the book Типология императива by Gusev and the article Русский язык в зеркале типологии: новации в императивной парадигме by Khrakovsky, both of whom mention these forms as outdated as well, except for идти and derivatives thereof

IMHO, not all derivatives of идти are the same: выйдемте or уйдёмте sound as outdated as поедемте. So really it's just those three that are still relatively widely used.


Справочная служба дает корректный ответ по теме:  Пойдемте — это давай пойдем.

Оба варианта стилистически нейтральны.

Что это за формы? Частицы давай и давайте обозначают  совместность действия в форме повелительного наклонения (это аналитическая форма), а пойдемте — особая синтетическая форма, образованная соединение формы изъявительного наклонения будущего времени с окончанием ТЕ, которое в повелит. наклонении обозначает множ. число.

Сравнить: (1) давай пойдем, давайТЕ пойдем, (2) иди, идиТЕ,  (3) пусть идет, пусть идут. Это разные формы повелительного наклонения.

ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС. Форма пойдемте не указывает число лиц, которым говорящий предлагает участвовать в действии.  Форма может выражать уважительное отношение, если обращена к одному лицу. Если обращаться к лицу, с которым говорящий на ты,  то используется переносная форма изъявительного наклонения: идем, пойдем. Но при этом она имеет значение повелительного наклонения.

А вот аналитические формы давай пойдем, давайте пойдем может выражать такое число: давай пойдем — обращение к одному лицу, давайте пойдем — обращение к нескольким лицам или выражение уважения.
Образование повелительного наклонения (3 формы)
